# Why `break` doesn't work in my thread?

Tags: python, loops, break

This is part of my python script:

```
   with open("/tmp/IpList.txt", "r+") as f:
    for ip in f:
        page = 1
        ip = ip.strip("\r\n")
        print ip
        while True:
            url = 'http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip%3a' + ip + '&qs=n&pq=ip%3a' + ip + '&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&first=' + str(page) + '&FORM=PERE'
            print url
            with open("/tmp/content.txt", "a") as out:
                content = ContentFunc()
                if "<cite>" in content and "</cite>" in content:
                    out.write(content)
                    with open("/tmp/result.txt", "a+") as result:
                        res = CiteParser()
                        result.write(res.encode('utf-8'))
                    page += 10
                else:
                    break
```

I am going to handle my hosts from bing web site.

My `break` doesn't work here. when IPs are finished it goes and again reads first line of `IpList.txt` ... why?

Comment: `result.close()` is unnecessary, as you use `with`, which automatically closes the file.

Comment: That check does not do what you think it does, You compare if the string `"<cite>"` is true (which is always the case) *and* if `"</cite>"` is in content.

Comment: `if "<cite>"` is *always true*; the rest of that test is never executed. Boolean logic is not like English; you have to be explicit in your test. `if "<cite>" in content and "</cite>" in content:`.

Comment: how can I correct it? could you possibly put answer ?

Comment: No this is not always true..may be I put the IP wrong..so there is not  <cite> and it should break from loop and goes to next line of IpList.txt

Comment: @MortezaLSC nobody said the whole statement would be always true, it just won't do what you think it does. Aside from that, without knowing ContentFunc, CiteParser and your actual content we can't say much, you should post a minimal *reproducible* example.

Comment: Ok...`ContentFunc()` returns contents from bing pages. and `CiteParser()` returns hosts between `<cite>..</cite>`

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters  Thank you...but why my loop doesn't beak...there are no problem I thin in my code